# Python - How to create capsule from sphere via Bmesh?

Tags: python, bmesh

I want to make a capsule by changing the distance between the two halves of the sphere to a certain depth

[image]

[image]

```
import bpy
import bmesh

bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_uvsphere(bm, u_segments=8, v_segments=9, radius=2)

name = 'Capsule'
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
mesh.update()
bm.free()

object = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(object)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create_uvsphere` now takes a `diameter` argument rather than `radius` despite what the manual [claims](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.create_uvsphere).  EDIT: From the comments, what you want to do is move the top half of the sphere up an increment and the bottom half down the same increment.  Here's code to do that:

```py
import bmesh

bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_uvsphere(bm, u_segments=8, v_segments=9, diameter=2)
delta_Z = WHATEVER_YOU_WANT
bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
for vert in bm.verts:
    if vert.co[2] < 0:
        vert.co[2] -= delta_Z
    elif vert.co[2] > 0:
        vert.co[2] += delta_Z

name = 'Capsule'
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
mesh.update()
bm.free()

object = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(object)
```

where scale_Z is how much you want to scale the result by.

Comment: I don't want to stretch the sphere, I want distance between the two halves of the sphere as shown in the image above

Comment: @Karan I changed the code to what you want.